# Blade pass Collection as String instead of Array

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Passing Collection to Vue through Blade, will be received as String instead of Array. In the past, usually it will be received as Array. Now it's received as JSON-encoded String. Anyone know why? Apparently, some old Vue files will still receive as Array.

### Sample code:

**view.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
  <div id="todos_view">
    <vue-component-here
      :todos="{{ $todosCollection }}"
    />
  </div>

  <script src="{{ mix('/js/test.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

**TodoView.vue**

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            todos: {
                type: Array, //This one should work. But instead, it will receive JSON-encoded String
                required: false
            }, ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**view.blade.php**

```php
@section('content')
  <div id="todos_view">
    <vue-component-here
      :todos='@json($todosCollection)'
    />
  </div>

  <script src="{{ mix('/js/test.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Tada!

P.S. - Make sure to use single quotes with @json!